# Similarity transformation for set of matrices represent the same group

Tags: matrices, group-theory

I am trying to solve the following problem, but I do not really know where to even start... If someone could help, I'd be very grateful.

For a set of matrices $S(g)$ forming a representation of group $G$, with $g \in G$, the similarity transformation of $S(g)$, i.e. $S'(g) = U S(g) U^{-1}$ is also a representation of $G$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:**  You need to show that $S'$ is also a homomorphism.

So check if $S'(gh)=S'(g)S'(h)\,,\forall g,h\in G$.  This should be pretty straightforward,  using that $S$ is a homomorphism, i.e. $S(gh)=S(g)S(h)$.

Comment: Ah, maybe I understand. So, $S'(gh) = U S(gh) U^{-1} = U S(g) S(h) U^{-1} =  US(g)U^{-1} US(h)U^{-1} = S'(g)(S'(h)$, which holds for all $g,h \in G$, and $gh \in G$ from the closure axiom?

Comment: @bjorn You got it.